# Windows 11 Desktop and File Folders Do Not Refresh Automatically

Tags: windows, file, directory

do you know why windows 11 is not refreshing after creating a new folder or file, or after renaming or deleting? I have to press F5 in order to see the changes I did.

Thank you very much for all your help/

To understand why Windows 11 does this. I have never had such issues with previous versions of windows.